# Python Multiplication different shape to numpy dot product

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to understand the python multiplication operator. I was always under the assumption that it performed a dot product when doing the following

```
a * b
```

however, the example below shows that different shapes are produced.

```
a = np.random.random((3, 3))
b = np.array([1,0,1])
```

Multiplication operator:

```
(a*b).shape
(3, 3)
```

Numpy dot product:

```
np.dot(a,b).shape
(3,)
```

What maths operation is the multiplication operator doing?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. `@` operator is sit product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(3, size=(3, 3))

Out[1]:

(A)  [[0 1 1]
      [0 2 2]
      [0 1 0]]

b = np.array([1,0,2]) 

Out[2]:

(B)  [1 0 2]
```

So in operation a*b it does element-wise multiply. Because dimensions mismatch it make "broadcast", and apply extrapolated "b" instead real "b".

```
(A)[[0 1 1]   (B)[[1 0 2]     [[0 0 2]   # [0x0, 1x0, 1x2] and so on
    [0 2 2]   *   [1 0 2]   =  [0 0 4]
    [0 1 0]]      [1 0 2]]     [0 0 0]]
```

On another hand, np.dot gives you matrix multiplying:

```
(A)[[0 1 1]   (B)[[1]     [[2]   # [0x1 + 1x0 + 1x2 = 2] and so on
    [0 2 2]   X   [0]   =  [4]
    [0 1 0]]      [2]]     [0]]
```

Comment: Nice job showing how to see the result happening. You might want to mention that `A @ B`, `A.dot(B)`, or most generally `np.dot(A, B)` are all ways to produce the desired dot product.

Answer (score 0):

One general answer is that the python multiplication operator has a different behaviour depending on the object it is applied to.

`numpy` objects are **not** python primitive types. `numpy` redefines the behaviour of the multiplication operator.

According to `numpy` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations):

> arithmetic operators on arrays apply elementwise

Reading the doc further you get your answer:

> Unlike in many matrix languages, the product operator * operates elementwise in NumPy arrays. The matrix product can be performed using the @ operator (in python >=3.5) or the dot function or method